# Young adult sci-fi - apocalypse where young people return to earth?

Tags: story-identification, novel, post-apocalyptic

It's not The Hundred.
The story starts out on another planet (Mars?). Details that I remember:

- Humans had left earth and gone to another planet after some unnamed Earth apocalypse, thinking no humans remained on Earth.
- The kids chosen to return to Earth may have been orphans.
- I remember the kids' oxygen source being pressed upon them if they forgot to return to their pod fast enough.
- There were no pets on the other planet, but they had video (I say video, because it was in the future, but you could say "film," as well) of cats, and when the young protagonist gets to earth, he calls a bird a "cat thing".
- Everyone on the other planet was dark-haired.
- Unexpectedly, Earth had survivors.
- The survivors may have lived by the sea.
- The kids wanted to stay on Earth, but the adults on the other planet didn't want that.

More details: It's a novel and I'm not sure. Likely pre-1975. Am thinking it might be Ireland but am really not sure. My friend who's asking said she also remembered that after being forced to use breathing apparatus on the other planet, the main character liked breathing the air of earth. I don't recall any alien or supernatural or extra powers. Everyone was human.

Does this sound at all familiar to anyone?

Comment: Any more details? _When_ did it air? _What_ network/country? Etc.

Comment: It's a novel and I'm not sure. Likely pre-1975. Am thinking it might be Ireland but am really not sure.  My friend who's asking said she also remembered that after being forced to use breathing apparatus on the other planet, the main character liked breathing the air of earth. I don't recall any alien or supernatural or extra powers. Everyone was human.

Comment: That's good info - you should add it to the main body of your question.

Comment: I was about to add an answer about its similarities to The 100, until I realized that I didn't actually read your first sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be Joan Clarke's 'The Happy Planet' from 1963. The plot is the same - colonists return to an Earth devastated by a meteor storm & not expecting any survivors - sounds the same, and the way the kids are forced to use their oxygen equipment definitely rings a bell.

Comment: I'm the person searching for the book, and my friend very kindly posted on here for me (thanks, friend!). Lee Edkhardt, I think you may be right! I hope so. I'll see if I can get a copy and see. This would be solving a mystery decades long :)

Comment: Thank you so much, Lee Eckhardt, your suggestion is correct and my friend has now ordered a hard copy to re-read.

Comment: @kworks If this is the correct answer, please upvote and accept it using the check mark on the left.